# How to implement design library to android app?

Tags: java, android, android-design-library

I wont to implement this design library to my project > https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/packages.html#design **(com.android.support:design:28.0.0)**. But when I'm syncing I have got error: Could not get unknown property 'com' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler. Please help. Thanks :)

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 29
  buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
  defaultConfig {
      applicationId "com.example.pyramid"
      minSdkVersion 15
      targetSdkVersion 29
      versionCode 1
      versionName "1.0"
      testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
  }
  buildTypes {
      release {
          minifyEnabled false
          proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
  }
}

dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
  implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
  implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support.design:28.0.0'
```

Comment: You got the quotes wrong, it should be `implementation 'com.android.support.design:28.0.0'`. Also, unrelated to the problem, but the design library was succeeded in androidx by the `com.google.android.material:material` library so you might want to use that instead.

Comment: **Still**.ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.android.support.design:28.0.0:
Affected Modules: app

Comment: Update the script in your question.

Comment: Remove the `design` library entirely if you wish to use google material components. One is a replacement for the other.

Comment: I must have got the `design` library because I wont to make a BottomNavigationBar

Comment: Any suggestions ?

Comment: Use `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigation` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think it is solved. I just copied all libraries from second project with `Bottom Navigation Activity` to my first project. `com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView` It's all :)